# MySQL Table Correlation

Tags: php, mysql, enums, correlation

I'm kinda a noob so I don't know if this is actually possible.

I have two field in my MySQL database that I want to correlate:

```
Level int(11)
Rank enum('Hobo','Shippai','NoLifer',Troublemaker','gangster') (and so it continues.)
```

I want so that `level 1=Hobo`, `level 2=Shippai` etc. etc.

Currently it looks like this:

`Level: {$ir['level']}`

And want it to look like this on the website:

```
Rank: Hobo
```

Thanks in advance for any help...

Edit:

Here's the code for the table:

> ";
>         $exp=(int)($ir['exp']/$ir['exp_needed']*100);
>         print "
>         **Name:** {$ir['username']}**Crystals:** {$cm}        
>         **Level:** {$ir['level']}
>         **Exp:** {$exp}%
>         **Money:** $fm
>          **Gang:** ";
>         $qs=$db->query("SELECT * FROM gangs WHERE gangID={$ir['gang']}");
>         $rs=$db->fetch_row($qs);
>         if(!$db->num_rows($qs) )
>         {
>         print "No Gang";
>         }
>         else
>         {
>         print" {$rs['gangNAME']} ";
>         }
>         print "
>         
>         
>         **Property:** {$ir['hNAME']}
>         **Days Old:** {$ir['daysold']} 
>          **Health:** {$ir['hp']}/{$ir['maxhp']}  
>         **Energy:**  {$ir['energy']}/{$ir['maxenergy']} 
>          **Brave:** {$ir['brave']}/{$ir['maxbrave']}  
>         **Will:**  {$ir['will']}/{$ir['maxwill']} 
>         
>         
>         
>           
> ";

Comment: Do you have one table or two? If there's just one, your fields are already concretely correlated. Each record represents a combination of the possible values of each field.

Comment: for some reason the entire code didn't show up in blockquote, and in code it didn't want to save the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new table called rank_define inside have, id(int, primary key, auto increment),  name(char20), add your named ranks so it looks like this:

id | name

1 | Hobo

2 | Shippai

In your code

```
$user_id = 1; // or whatever the users rank is
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM rank_define WHERE id='$user_id'");
```

This will return a result set so you will want to do:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "rank: " . $row['name'];  // will output rank: Hobo
}
```

I think this is what you mean, is it for a user account or something different? This is assuming no account and you are just searching for a result.

If it were to be part of a user account system you would want a table for users eg: id (auto inc, primary key, int), name, rank, (etc..)

In rank their rank is inserted from the rank_define table, so 1 = hobo, 2 = shippai etc. Then you would query that table

Updated answer:

Okay so you have the while loop.`while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_NUM)) {`.

It will go something like this:

```
    <table>
    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Name: " . $row['name'] . "</td>";  // will output their name / account whatever
        echo "<td>Rank: " . $row['rank'] . "</td>";  // will output their rank
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i need to print the result in a td cell. Here's the website so you can see what I mean: 174.164.71.37

Comment: It isn't loading for me, I assume that is your dynamic ip? So, are you wanting to write one result into a table or will it be more than one? Check my answer at the bottom in about 5 mins with an updated answer ;-)

Comment: its my public ip, which is forwarded to my server on port 80.

Comment: Still not letting me in, can you post a screeny to imgur of your website?

Comment: Looks nice. Does my updated post above help at all? If not let me know whats up with it :) the concept is the same though

Comment: I found a workaround, not quite what I wanted bit its ok. btw here's the domain for it: http://mafianor.info/login.php